# Selecting data intervals on Datachart with Mouse

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

I use stacked area chart and I want to select a datapoint interval with the mouse like below.

[image]

I know that some applications offer this feature however, I couldn't find  how to do it.

Could you please show me the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you needed is [`DataVisualization.Charting.Cursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use this combination of properties:

```
    // a few short references:
    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
    var cx = ca.CursorX;


    cx.IsUserEnabled = true;             // allow a cursor to be placed
    cx.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;    // allow it to be used for selecting
    ax.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;       // prevent from automatically zooming in
```

Here are the first and last values selected:

```
var x1 = cx.SelectionStart;
var x2 = cx.SelectionEnd;
```

Here are the first and last `DataPoints` selected:

```
var p1 = s.Points.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.XValue >= x1).First();
var p2 = s.Points.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.XValue <= x2).Last();
```

And the indices of the first and last `DataPoints`selected:

```
var i1 = s.Points.IndexOf(p1);
var i2 = s.Points.IndexOf(p2);
```

Now you can tell which points were selected:

```
textBox1.Text += (i2 - i1) + " points selected.\r\n\r\n";

for (int  i = i1; i < i2; i++)
{
    textBox1.Text += i + ".  " + chart1.Series[0].Points[i].ToString() + "\r\n";
    chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Color = Color.Red;

}
```

**Note**: The code to identify the starting and end points assumes that all `DataPoints` are added in **increasing x-value order**. Since you can add `DataPoints` in any order it will fail for instance when you insert out of order points! In that case you would instead collect the points in the selection (testing for both sides) in a `List<DataPoint>` and then enumerate this list.